# How update vue variable if API variable changed?

Tags: vue.js

I would like to use VUE in combination with Pano2VR. Pano2VR has an API (https://ggnome.com/doc/javascript-api/) that allows me to use the value of a variable from Pano2VR in Vue.

I programmed a code that finds the value of a variable from Pano2VR and assigns that value to the VUE.

If I change the value of a variable in VUE, I can also change it in Pano2VR.
The problem, however, is that I need that if the value of a variable in Pano2VR changes, it also changes automatically in VUE.

The code I have below is what works for me so far, except for updating the values in Vue, if the value of the variable in Pano2VR changes.

Can someone help me how to do it ? May thanks for your time and help.

```js
const app = new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        dude: pano.getVariableValue('vue_text')
        // save value from variable "vue_text" from Pano2VR into dude
    },

    methods: {
        update: function () {
            this.dude = 'Lama lamová',
            pano.setVariableValue('vue_text', this.dude);
            // update Pano2VR variable
        }
    },
})
```

```html
<div id="app" @click="update">
  {{ dude }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Pano2VR has a [`varchanged_VARNAME` event](https://ggnome.com/doc/javascript-api/#events) that occurs for variable changes. You could hook into that to update Vue:

```js
const app = new Vue ({
  mounted() {
    pano.on('varchanged_vue_text', () => {
      this.dude = pano.getVariableValue('vue_text')
    })
  }
})
```